How to get Demo Clients Using Mindbody API Python
Can anyone tell me the steps to get the demo clients from Mind-Body? As of now, I created a basic developer account and have the API key from that account. However, when I go to this URL, https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/ui/documentation/public-api#/http/api-endpoints/client/get-clients, and enter the token, I get an empty response. Any help would be appreciated.
REQUEST
curl -X GET -G \
  --url 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clients'  \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'siteId: -99' \
  -H 'authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWJzY3JpYmVySWQiOiItOTkiLCJpZCI6IjE2NDE4NjMiLCJsb2dpbiI6Im1pbmRib2R5c2FuZGJveDk5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImFjY2VzcyI6IlN0YWZmIiwiZXhwIjoxNzMxMjUxMTY4LCJuYmYiOjE3MzExNjQ3Njh9.xSmMWoQaNlvnEbth2UQeiGx-ZFNoVskEdWLPcu9CnmE' \
  -H 'API-Key: 2799edb2d39f4eb9b7cb1a817fda0f08' \
  -d 'request.clientIDs[0]=request.clientIDs9' \
  -d 'request.clientIDs[1]=request.clientIDs0' \
  -d 'request.clientIDs[2]=request.clientIDs1' \
  -d 'request.includeInactive=false' \
  -d 'request.isProspect=false' \
  -d 'request.lastModifiedDate=2016-03-13T12%3A52%3A32.123Z' \
  -d 'request.limit=62' \
  -d 'request.offset=100' \
  -d 'request.searchText=request.searchText0' \
  -d 'request.uniqueIds[0]=123' \
  -d 'request.uniqueIds[1]=124' \
  -d 'request.uniqueIds[2]=125'

RESPONSE
{"PaginationResponse":{"RequestedLimit":62,"RequestedOffset":100,"PageSize":0,"TotalResults":0},"Clients":[]}


It was due to some extra params being passed in the request after removing those it worked fine.

curl -X GET -G \   --url
'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clients'  \   -H
'Accept: application/json' \   -H 'siteId: -99' \   -H 'authorization:
auth token'
\   -H 'API-Key: apikey' \   -d
'request.includeInactive=false' \   -d 'request.isProspect=false' \
-d 'request.lastModifiedDate=2024-11-01T00%3A00%3A00Z' \   -d 'request.limit=1000'

